# Open Custom Accordion from Link

Tags: jquery, content-management-system, accordion, expressionengine

I know there are many posts on this subject, but I have created a custom accordion due to my HTML markup. Below is my JQuery.

```
$(function(){
  hide(0);
  $('.accordion > h1').click(function(){
    hide($('.accordion').index($(this).parent()));
  });
  function hide(i){
    $('.accordion').removeClass('active');
    $('.accordion:eq(' + i + ')').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

Here is my HTML for the Accordion. Note I use ExpressionEngine CMS.

```
<section class="module flag-{style} {page_module_style}">
  <h1 id="row-id{row_id}">{header}</h1>
  <div class="copy">
    {copy}
  </div>
</section>
```

I use CSS to give it the Accordion look. the link will be http://siteurl.com/page#row-id1234, I need to figure out how to make it to where when I link to the specific accordion tab with its ID that it will open and focus on that tab.

Answer (score 0):

When the window is ready get the current hash and find the element that matches that id:

```
function getHash() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  return hash.substring(1); // remove #
}

$(function(){
  activeTab = $(getHash()).parent()

  hide($('.accordion').index(activeTab));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm having to break apart your code, it focuses on the accordion, but it does not open it up. Also for some reason it jacks up my JQuery Slideshow that I have on the page.